# Django Rest Framework: ModelSerializer and choosing fields per HTTP METHOD

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Say I have a phone book with 3 fields and a model to represent it:

1. Name
2. Age
3. Phone

I'm writing an API to post new entries, get existing entries and modify existing entries. For the sake of this question, my constraints are:

- for POST I'd like to be able to write all three fields when creating a new record.
- for GET I'd like to return only the `Age` and `Phone`
- for PUT I'd like to allow only the `phone` field to be updated.

Given the rigidness of the class meta and where I can define `extra_kwargs` with definitions for each field such as `read_only` and `write_only` -- Will I need three separate `ModelSerializer` classes? or can I somehow have some kind of condition in a single `ModelSerializer` in order to support my constraints.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or can I somehow have some kind of condition in a single
>   ModelSerializer in order to support my constraints.

Yes, you can in fact when most people start off using DRF. This is the approach taken. Certainly, I went down that path myself. But it's just not worth it.

It's much much easier and fewer lines of code to use multiple serializes. Specially if you are using Views instead of Viewsets. If you are using Viewsets, override the `get_serializer_class`